# Calculate GWESP for a matrix with fixed decay parameter

Tags: r, matrix, igraph

I'm wondering if there exist pre-programed `R` functions that can calculate geometrically weighted edgewise shared partners (GWESP, per [Hunter (2007)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0378873306000396?via%3Dihub)) for a given adjacency matrix with fixed decay parameter (alpha) and then return the estimated values also in matrix form?

I've looked at `xergm` and `igraph` packages but could not find one, they only estimate GWESP during model (network models) fitting but that's not what I want to do here. I only need a function to calculate GWESP for a given adjacency matrix and return the estimated GWESP value (with fixed decay parameter) for each dyad of the adjacency matrix in matrix form as well.

For example

```
# for a given adjacency matrix (adjm)
adjm <- matrix(sample(0:1, 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.6,0.4)), nc=10)

# apply some functions to calculate GWESP for each dyad of adjm (and fix alpha at some value) and return a matrix of the same dimension filled with estimated GWESP values

somefunction(adjm, alpha = somevalue)
```

Comment: igraph developer here. Not an answer to your question, hence keeping it in a comment. My understanding is that things like GWESP are artificial measures without any intuitive or practical interpretation. They were introduced to avoid degeneracy in exponential random graph models. There is no reason to calculate such measures in isolation—they're only useful to define certain ERGM, but even then, the interpretation of those random graph models is problematic. Thus, it would not make much sense to include such quantities in a general purpose network analysis package like igraph.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say that you want GWESP in matrix form? This measure (at least the version I am familiar with) characterizes an entire graph, not a single pair of vertices within the graph. If you want to compute how many common neighbours each pair of vertices has, you can simply take the square of the adjacency matrix. To restrict that to connected pairs, do an element-wise multiplication of the result with the adjacency matrix.

Comment: @Szabolcs
Thanks for your reply. It is indeed an misunderstanding of GWESP on my part. I originally want to convert dyadic data of adjacency matrix format to panel data (as I attempted to merge it with some hierarchical variables) and was thinking if I could use some simple functions to obtain those structural variables (2-star, gwdegree, gwesp, etc.) and put them into the converted panel data without actually running ERGM.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yet with hindsight, this idea might not make much sense in the context of dyadic panel data (I would really like to hear your thought on this). And, thanks so much for sharing this super easy tips for calculating common neighbors between a pair of nodes.